# accessing the express session from the socket io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

My question is about the getting username val what I send to view via express-handlebars.
In this chatting app, The username is accessible in html code and it can    changeable. İf someone change the username which is content of h4 tag,(from John Doe to Doe John), it affect all clients. Also I use express-session and mongostore to store the sessions and I know I cant access session without req. So what is your offer to solve this issue?(accesing the session) Thanks in advance.

that's the client side

```
  <h4 id="username">{{username}}</h4>
    <div class="chat">
      <ul class="chat-box"></ul>
    </div>
    <div class="chat-user">
      <form io="form-chat" class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-controll" id="text-chat" name="text-chat" value="">
        </div>
        <button>send`enter code here`</button>
      </form>
```

that s the server side

```
function socket(io) {

    io.on('connection', function(socket) {
        socket.on('chat message', function(msg) {
            console.log(splitUsername[0]);*/
            io.emit('chat message', msg);
        });
    });
}

module.exports = socket;
```

Comment: https://github.com/christopheranderson/express-session-socket.io

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Never trust the clients** (store important variables server-side, instead of relying on the clients)

I would make a *simple verification* (*pick username*) protocol before being able to use the chat.

```
const _onlineUsernames = {};
const MAX_USERNAME_LENGTH = 16;
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
 //.: Login (Pick Username)
 socket.on('enter',function(username){
  if(username){ //did we really receive a username?
   if(username.length!=0 && username.length<=MAX_USERNAME_LENGTH){
    if(!_onlineUsernames[username]){
    //username not in use, add to online list & verify :
    _onlineUsernames[username] = {sid:socket.id}; 
    socket.chat_verified = true; //used to verify username has been picked
    socket.chat_username = username; //store in the socket
    }else{socket.emit('error', 'username currently in use');}
   }else{socket.emit('error', 'length of username supplied');}
  }else{socket.emit('error', 'no username supplied');}
 });
 //.: Chat Logic
 socket.on('chat message', function(msg) {
  if(socket.chat_verified){ // Check if the user is verified (previously picked username)
    console.log(socket.chat_username);
    // Here, I would do some escaping/sanitation before emiting the message, 
    // mainly to prevent client-to-client injection (sanitation/escaping can be done in the client-side instead)
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  }else{ socket.emit('error', 'chat_verification_required'); }
 });
 //.: Login (Pick Username)
 socket.on('disconnect',function(){
  // Check if disconnected user was verified (picked username)
  if(socket.chat_verified){ delete _onlineUsernames[socket.chat_username]; }//username is free to be used again
 });
});
```

The clients won't be able of using the chat until they verify a username (socket "enter" event)

If you are concerned about security, you should also sanitize/escape the messages of the clients. *example* : a client sending the following message (`<script>alert('injected js!);</script>`)

---

**EDIT:** (Question specifically asks about **accessing the session from the socket**)

Using **[express-session-socket.io](https://github.com/christopheranderson/express-session-socket.io)** middleware to expose express session objects inside socket.io (similar to what I did with storing the username inside the socket)

Code Example : Simple (since you probably already have a sessionStore defined)

```
io.use(require('express-session-socket.io')(sessionStore, 'secret', function (err, session, socket, next) {
    if (err) next(err);
    socket.session = session;
    next();
}));
```